# Combining join and select statement in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ to SQL to perform select data from multiple tables after performing some computations on them. While performing the computations in the select statement, I would like to have the ability to reuse the results of a previous computation.

For instance:

```
var result = from da in DataA
             join db in DataB
             on da.colA = db.colB
             select new ClassA
             {
                fieldA = da.a + db.b,
                fieldB = fieldA + db.c
             };
```

Please note: fieldA and fieldB are fields in ClassA.

Now, LINQ to SQL doesn't allow the second statement:

```
fieldB = fieldA + db.c
```

So, I need to recalculate the value of fieldA to compute fieldB as:

```
fieldB = da.a + db.b + db.c
```

Is there any way for me to reuse the results of fieldA when I compute the value of fieldB in LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Lookup the `let` statement. Not sure if it works in LinQ to SQL though, it's extremely outdated and unsupported

Comment: You should consider using properties instead of public fields.

Comment: fieldB = fieldA + db.c equals da.a + db.b + db.c 
But second sentence says, fieldB = db.a + db.b + db.c There are diffirent things. Can you check your information.

Comment: I've edited the question. Thank you @BaşarKaya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `let` statement in LINQ is used to create temporary values that can be used later in a query. In LINQ to Objects, it essentially causes an intermediate `Select` that creates a new anonymous object containing the `let` value as well as the original values, so it isn't necessarily an efficiency improvement. In LINQ to SQL a nested `SELECT` is used to compute the intermediate expression.

```
var result = from da in DataA
             join db in DataB
             on da.colA = db.colB
             let fieldA = da.a + db.b
             select new ClassA
             {
                fieldA,
                fieldB = fieldA + db.c
             };
```